# How are the two typecasts different?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm doing a MOOC on Coursera and this code doesn't work:

```
unsigned int W, H, D;     
uint64_t total_weight = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    cin >> W >> H >> D;
    total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W * H * D);
}
total_weight *= R;
cout << total_weight;
```

However, this one does:

```
unsigned int W, H, D;     
uint64_t total_weight = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    cin >> W >> H >> D;
    total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D;
}
total_weight *= R;
cout << total_weight;
```

As you can see, the difference is in this line:

```
total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D;
```

How is that cast different from

```
total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W * H * D);
```

?

Comment: the difference is in the order of operations

Comment: The cast only takes place on the first item (W) for the first example, and their product in the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W * H * D);
```

Here `W * H * D` is calculated as a multiplication of `unsigned int`s and then casted to `uint64_t` which does not save you from the potential overflow while `W * H * D` is calculated.

```
total_weight += static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D;
```

Here `static_cast<uint64_t>(W) * H * D` is calculated as a multiplication of `uint64_t`s as `W` is casted to `uint64_t` and `H`, `D` promoted to `uint64_t` as well. So there are less chances to suffer from the overflow during multiplication in this case.

---

Relevant conversion rules are described as follows:

> 8 Expressions [expr]
>
> 11 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 11.5.2 Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>   integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.

And:

> 7.15 Integer conversion rank [conv.rank]
>
> 1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as
>   follows:
>
> ...
>
> 1.3 The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be
>   greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the
>   rank of signed char.
>
> 1.4 The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.